# Split a string at every occurrence of particular character?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I would like to pass a sequence of characters into a function as a string and have it return to me that string split at the following characters:

```
@ # $ % ^ & *
```

such that if the string is

```
'hey#man^you*are#awesome'
```

the program returns

'hey man you are awesome'

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to split or to replace with a space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split the string you can use `String#split`

```
'hey#man^you*are#awesome'.split(/[@#$%^&*]/)
#=> ["hey", "man", "you", "are", "awesome"]
```

to bring it back together, you can use `Array#join`

```
'hey#man^you*are#awesome'.split(/[@#$%^&*]/).join(' ')
#=> "hey man you are awesome"
```

`split` and `join` should be self-explanatory. The interesting part is the regular expression `/[@#$%^&*]/` which matches any of the characters inside the character class `[...]`. The above code is essentially equivalent to

```
'hey#man^you*are#awesome'.gsub(/[@#$%^&*]/, ' ')
#=> "hey man you are awesome"
```

where the `gsub` means "globally substitute any occurence of @#$%^&* with a space".

Comment: Good explanation, p11y. +1 You mention both `split/join` and `gsub` as options, but seem to favor the former.  I would think `gsub` would preferable since it works on the string directly, rather than converting to an array and then back to a string.  I personally think `gsub` reads better as well.  What is your thinking on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [String#tr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-tr), which avoids the need to convert an array back to a string:

```
'hey#man^you*are#awesome'.tr('@#$%^&*', '       ')
  #=> "hey man you are awesome"
```